# python, please tell me whats wrong

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, raw-input

python,please help. I want this code to ask someone if they are ok with the grade. if they say yes, it prints good! if they say no, it says oh well! if they dont say yes or no, i want it to print " please enter yes or no" and keep asking them that until they finally say yes or no. This is what i have so far and when i run it and DONT type yes or no, it spams "please enter yes or no" millions of time

```
theanswer= raw_input("Are you ok with that grade?")
while theanswer:
    if theanswer == ("yes"):
        print ("good!")
        break
    elif theanswer == ("no"):
        print ("oh well")
        break
    else: 
        print "enter yes or no"
```

what do i need to do so that it works, ive been trying a lot

Comment: Check the place where you're modifying `theanswer` inside the loop...

Comment: im not editing it, i dont know if i did, could u tell me?

Comment: Exactly. So what is the value of `theanswer` on the next iteration?

Answer (score 7):

You need to have a blocking call in your `else` statement. Otherwise you will have an infinite loop because `theanswer` will always be true. Like asking for input:

```
theanswer= raw_input("Are you ok with that grade?")
while theanswer:
    if theanswer == ("yes"):
        print ("good!")
        break
    elif theanswer == ("no"):
        print ("oh well")
        break
    else: 
        theanswer= raw_input("Please enter yes or no")
```

Here is a good resorce on [Blocking vs Non-Blocking I/O](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241429/blocking-io-vs-non-blocking-io-looking-for-good-articles). It's an important fundamental in any application.

Comment: @EvanWestphal please try and take this as a learning experience. Here's a good resource on [Blocking vs Non-Blocking I/O](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241429/blocking-io-vs-non-blocking-io-looking-for-good-articles). It'll be good to understand the difference in a future coding career :)

Comment: @EvanWestphal Also, if this worked for you, please select it as the accepted solution :)

Answer (score 3):

or this (this separates the input logic from what you do with the answer):

```
theanswer = raw_input("Are you ok with that grade?")
while theanswer not in ('yes', 'no'):
    theanswer = raw_input('Please enter yes or no')

if theanswer == "yes":
    print("good!")
elif theanswer == "no":
    print("oh well")
```

Comment: You're missing the initial question of `"Are you ok with your grade?"`

Answer (score 1):

Basically in your code you have a while loop running that will only break if *theanswer == yes or == no*.
You are also not giving the possibility of changing the value of *theanswer* in your loop therefore => infinity loop.

add this to your code:

```
else: 

        print "enter yes or no"
        theanswer= raw_input("Are you ok with that grade?")
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with recursion

```
def get_user_input(text):
    theanswer= raw_input(text)
    if theanswer == 'yes':
        print('good!')
    elif theanswer == ("no"):
        print('oh well')
    else: 
        get_user_input('enter yes or no')

get_user_input('Are you ok with that grade?')
```

Comment: I like the recursive solution, much safer than a inline while loop.